# How does name resolution work when classes are derived across modules?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Classes B and C both derive from base class A, and neither override A's method test().  B is defined in the same module as A; C is defined in a separate module.  How is it that calling B.test() prints "hello", but calling C.test() fails?  Shouldn't either invocation end up executing A.test() and therefore be able to resolve the symbol "message" in mod1's namespace?

I'd also gratefully receive hints on where this behaviour is documented as I've been unable to turn up anything.  How are names resolved when C.test() is called, and can "message" be injected into one of the namespaces somehow?

FWIW, the reason I haven't used an instance variable (e.g. set A.message = "hello") is because I'm wanting to access a "global" singleton object and don't want to have an explicit referent to it in every other object.

mod1.py:

```
import mod2

class A(object):
  def test(self):
    print message

class B(A):
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  message = "hello"
  A().test()
  B().test()
  mod2.C().test()
```

mod2.py:

```
import mod1

class C(mod1.A):
  pass
```

output is:

```
$ python mod1.py 
hello
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod1.py", line 14, in <module>
    mod2.C().test()
  File "mod1.py", line 5, in test
    print message
NameError: global name 'message' is not defined
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Side note: (Other) problems easily appear when you do cross-imports like this. For instance, `python mod2.py` fails because `mod1.A` is not yet defined when class `C` is defined. My experience is that cross-imports like this usually indicate that some code would be more logically be moved somewhere else, until no cross-imports remain.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to have an explicit referent to it in every other object"?  I'm not sure I understand the problem with using a class attribute: `A.message = "hello"` sets a *class* attribute which is *not stored* in the class instances.

Comment: @EOL, the "global" in my real world problem is a database handle.  I'd rather not have to store it in the object/class because there are many objects and many types which need to access the db.  Another issue is that I'm passing these objects via `multiprocessing` `Queue`s and the database handle is required to be process-specific, so adding it to the objects/classes is messy.  Finally, the aim is that the base classes are user-extensible, hence cross-module.  Ideally, I'm hoping to understand why my expectations on how the name resolutions are wrong and work out where to go from there.

Comment: I see. Yeah, it makes sense to use a global, here. I am not sure I see how the requirement of user-extensibility is related to cross-*importing*: I was referring to the fact that it would be better to not have `mod1.py` do `import mod2` (if `mod2.py` does `import mod1`). I wonder if the problem is not related to this cross-import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EOL is correct, moving the "main" part of the program into a new file mod3.py does indeed make things work.

http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/ further clarifies the issue.

In my original question, it turns out that the variable `message` ist stored in the `__main__` module namespace because mod1.py is being run as a script.  mod2 imports mod1, but it gets a separate `mod1` namespace, where the variable `message` does not exist.  The following code snippet demonstrates more clearly as it writes `message` into `mod1`'s namespace (not that I'd recommend this be done in real life), causing the expected behaviour.

```
import sys

class A(object):
  def test(self):
    print message

class B(A):
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import mod2
  message = "hello"
  sys.modules["mod1"].message = message
  A().test()
  B().test()
  mod2.C().test()
```

I think the best real-world fix is to move the "main" part of the program into a separate module, as EOL implies, or do:

```
class A(object):
  def test(self):
    print message

class B(A):
  pass

def main():
  global message
  message = "hello"
  A().test()
  B().test()

  # resolve circular import by importing in local scope
  import mod2
  mod2.C().test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # break into mod1 namespace from __main__ namespace
  import mod1
  mod1.main()
```

Comment: So, does this mean that in the original main program, `A().test()` makes `message` be interpreted in the `test()` function as `sys.modules['__main__'].message`, but that `mod2.C().test()` makes `message` be interpreted as `mod1.message`? I would be curious to know how things work inside the interpreter, if this is the case. The bytecode for `test()` simply read `LOAD_GLOBAL message`: what allows the interpreter to interpret this differently in `A().test()` and in `mod2.C().test()`?

Comment: @EOL, yes, exactly.  mod1.py ends up being available twice as `sys.modules['__main__']` and `sys.modules['mod1']`.  There are two instances of `A.test()`, one in each module.  In the example, `A().test()` calls the former, `mod2.C().test()` ends up calling the latter.  If you follow ceval.c in the python source, it shows that `LOAD_GLOBAL` reads the global symbol table from wherever the calling function was defined (this is also as documented).  The issue is that because of the `__main__` namespace there are two versions of the calling function `A.test()`.  Hence my confusion!

Comment: Thank you, everything seems clear, now. +1 for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a class attribute instead of a global? The following works

```
import mod2

class A(object):

    message = "Hello"  # Class attribute (not duplicated in instances)

    def test(self):
        print self.message  # Class A attribute can be overridden by subclasses

class B(A):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    A().test()
    B().test()
    mod2.C().test()
```

Not using globals is cleaner: in the code above, `message` is explicitly attached to the class it is used in.

---

That said, I am also very curious as to why the global `message` is not found by `mod2.C().test()`.

Things work as expected, though, *if the cross-importing is removed* (no main program in `mod1.py`, and no `import mod2`): importing `mod1` and `mod2` from `mod3.py`, doing `mod1.message = "Hello"` there and `mod2.C().test()` works. I am therefore wondering if the problem is not related to cross-importing…

Comment: I think I've now got it worked it out -- see answer below and thanks for your assistance.